# Задать символу номер

Tags: python

Есть код:

```
s=str(input("Enter string"))
print(s)
for i in range(len(s)):
print(i)
```

Как зделать чтобы к цифре присваивалась буква и начиналось с 1 что-то типо:

```
"qwerty" <--(строка)
[1] [q],
[2] [w]...
```

и так далее ?

Answer (score 2):

```
for i, e in enumerate(s):
    print('[{0}] [{1}]'.format(i + 1, e))
```

Comment: `enumerate` вторым параметром принимает начальный номер, т.е. если написать `enumerate(s, 1)` (или `enumerate(s, start=1)`), то можно будет обойтись без `+ 1` в цикле.

Answer (score 1):

```
ei = [[e, i] for e, i in enumerate(input('Enter string: '), start=1)]
print(ei)

from itertools import chain
p = '[{}] [{}],\n'*len(ei)
print(p.format(*chain(*ei)))
```

out:

```
Enter string: qw
[[1, 'q'], [2, 'w']]
[1] [q],
[2] [w],
```